# Extracting contents of placeholders inside curly braces prefixed with dollar symbol

Tags: java, regex

Lets say I have a string `"lore epsum dimsum ${ITEM_NAME} wonton kimchi"`.

I have created a regex that can extract `${ITEM_NAME}` from anywhere in the string. That regex is, `.{(.*.*)}`.

How can I customize this regex to extract just the string between `${}` which is `ITEM_NAME`?

Comment: It is a `String regex = "\\$\\{([^{}]*)\\}";`

Comment: The original solution has a problem with strings like `lore epsum dimsum ${ITEM_NAME} wonton ${ANOTHER_NAME} kimchi`, Wiktor's solution is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `{(.*.*)}` pattern, you extract any substrings between the leftmost `{` and rightmost `}`.

You need

```java
\$\{([^{}]*)\}
```

In Java:

```java
String regex = "\\$\\{([^{}]*)\\}";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qvKEzH/1).

If there is an explicit requirement to only match alphanumeric/underscore chars inside `${...}`, you can replace `[^{}]*` with `\w+` / `\w*` pattern (doubling the backslashes in Java string literal).

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/jMMCCa):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String text = "lore epsum dimsum ${ITEM_NAME} wonton kimchi ${ITEM_NAME_2}";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^{}]*)}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        while(m.find()) {
            res.add(m.group(1));
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[ITEM_NAME, ITEM_NAME_2]
```